# Django ORM magic. Bug or a feature?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

```
data = self.get_queryset()\
            .annotate(total=Func(Sum('money_field'), Value('CHAR'), function="CONVERT"))\
            .filter(date__lt=end, date__gte=start)
```

if i execute `data.query` - it works fine, but `data.all()` Raise MySQL error.

reason of this magic is Django Func(), when i try pass constant param (without brackets) -- threre is one way to do it: Using django Value().

It works fine, when i get query throught data.query, but when execute -- mysql add additional quotes,

**Working wariant is:**

```
data = self.get_queryset()\
            .annotate(total=Func(Sum('money_field'), Value('CHAR'), function="CONVERT"))\
            .filter(date__lt=end, date__gte=start)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(str(data.query).replace('%', '%%'), [])
data_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

Anyone can say WTF ?

Comment: IMO you're doing something strange. `Func()` accepts `F` expressions, which will be compiled to fields, while you trying to pass aggregation functions there

Comment: SELECT  CONVERT(Sum(`money_field`), CHAR) as total GROUP BY total.
Then return it directry to browser, as JSON 
(Convert decimal to char)

Answer (score 0):

UPD 2:
Printing query of queryset looks like:

```
SELECT `blankapp_modela`.`id`, `blankapp_modela`.`decimal_field`, 
CONVERT(SUM(`blankapp_modela`.`decimal_field`), CHAR) AS `total` FROM 
`blankapp_modela` GROUP BY `blankapp_modela`.`id` ORDER BY NULL
```

Looking deeper in mysql cursor I found next:

```
SELECT `blankapp_modela`.`id`, `blankapp_modela`.`decimal_field`, 
CONVERT(SUM(`blankapp_modela`.`decimal_field`), 'CHAR') AS `total` FROM 
`blankapp_modela` GROUP BY `blankapp_modela`.`id` ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 21
```

`CHAR` is wrapped to quotes, so it is not right.
Don't know the right solution for now.
It is not django issue, it is MySQLdb behavior.

Comment: CONVERT TO WHAT ? this function require second param.
(and param must not be s string, but constant without quotes or single quotes)

Comment: Try put `Value()` here, but use annotate for aggregation

Comment: You read question this post? It works only for generting query! But not when executing (except manualy execution.)... `data.query` works fine, but `data.all()` doesn`t! ... data.all() Raise mysql error

Comment: Thats i try to say... Magic... 999layers of protection)). 
Maybe Django shoud insert value directly into sql str, and not as %s parameter. 
Maybe its time to fix django sourses.

Comment: It is not a django issue. Parameters for a query are passed to each backend separetly, and each backend relsoves params in its own way.